# Calling getElementById("....") in init function() instead of the function who wants to do something with it

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, init

Question came up while working on following homework: Create 4 `divs` who change their color when I click on a `button`.

It's all working but my teacher uses the `init function` for getting the `divs` via `getElementById("div1")` and I use the `changeColorFunction()` itself and did not use an `init function` at all. See below:

My solution:

```
function changeColor () {

    document.getElementById("div1").style.background = createNewColor();
    document.getElementById("div2").style.background = createNewColor();
    document.getElementById("div3").style.background = createNewColor();
    document.getElementById("div4").style.background = createNewColor();

}
```

My teachers solution:

```
    var d1,d2,d3,d4;

    function init(){

    d1 = document.getElementById("d1");
    d2 = document.getElementById("d2");
    d3 = document.getElementById("d3");
    d4 = document.getElementById("d4");
    }
window.onload = init;
```

Its just a question about the best time/location for getting the `elements`.
With this little piece of code I guess not that big a difference but when DOES it matter?

When this project grows will the user ever recognize with my solution that the browser always has to get the `elements` first before code can run on them?

Hope you can follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to access those `div`s many times, it may be beneficial to cache them beforehand, which is what your teacher is doing.

That is, it'll be ***faster*** to change the `style` of a cached `DOM` element, stored in variable, then to fetch it from the DOM tree, using `getElementById`, everytime you want to change its style.

The difference, however, is almost negligible, but as always, the best way to see it, is to benchmark it. I've created a [**jsperf.com**](http://jsperf.com) test case to illustrate it. You can check [**here**](http://jsperf.com/cachegetelementbyid) the results and play with it:

```
Testing in Chrome 21.0.1180.83 32-bit on Windows Server 2008 R2 / 7 64-bit
+-----------------------+------------------------------------------------+
| Test                  |  Ops/sec                                       |
+-----------------------+------------------------------------------------+
| Cached getElementById |  584,606 ±2.62% fastest                        |
+-----------------------+------------------------------------------------+
| getElementById        |  422,957 ±1.27% 27% slower                     |
+-----------------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for this. Interesting see to the actual time.

Answer (score 0):

It makes practically no difference. There *may* be very very very tiny performance differences on old browsers. You aren't creating any global variables, which means if you have to change something else on the same `div`, you'll have to get it by ID again. Your professor's method will let him just use the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the difference is that your teacher is kind of "caching" the divs.
This means that when he has to change a color, he won't have to search the page with getElementById every time, because he has them in variables.

In your case, each time you'll want to change the divs color, you'll be scanning the page to get the divs, even though you already found them before.

This could make a difference in big pages.